# How to hook an API function

Tags: hook, windows-ce

I have to intercept a DLL that calls a function in the coredll.dll of `Windows CE 5.0`. The DLL is not in ROM. How can I hook the call of the testee and redirect it to my own function?

Example:  When the DLL code calls RegFlushKey I don't want the actual code be executed because it's very time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely think it's non-extensible, not maintainable, likely to cause problems in a real-world deplyment and generally an insane thing to be doing, but you could hook the RegFlushKey API directly, so that *all* calls to it get re-routed.  It's too complex for a SO post, but [there's a decent explanation over on Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/124496/Easy-API-hooking-in-Windows-CE).

I'd be far more inclined to find any sort of workaround, be it background threading calls to the DLL or whatever long before I'd resort to API hooking.

Comment: `SetProcPermissions` is not available in WEC2013 anymore. Also it might be that the API set is not accessible in that way. How would you implement this in WEC2013?